# ASPNET MVC formatting string in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, formatting

I want to make an MVC View, which shows a string.

The string contains whitespaces (`" "`, `"/t"`, `"/n"`) and I want to show it in format defined in string.

My problem is, that if I return the string as `ViewBag` message, all of these whitespaces are lost. Is there any solution to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around, replace `\t` with `&nbsp` and `\n` with `<br/>` and you could use,

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Something)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a web one where the browser ignores extraneous space.  You need to convert all space characters to   if you want to retain the number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to achieve this.

use [pre htnml tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

or

you have to hard code the space chars into   [non-breaking white spaces](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/g/bldefnonbrkspc.htm).

hope it will help you to some extent.